# How can I specify daylight timezone status when adding an event?

Tags: google-calendar

As I write this, I'm in EST (GMT - 5), and I'm trying to add an event for a couple of months from now when I will be in EDT (GMT - 4).  Say the event is at 12:00 noon.  When I add the event, it adds at noon, but **this is incorrect** because after the time change, the event will move an hour earlier on the calendar. 
I'm adding like this (and even specifying EDT):

[image]

But the event is created like this:
[image]

I could remember this trap and mentally correct for it, but what I really want is to be able to specify a time like 3/20/2014 at 12:00 in Eastern time, and have the app **determine** that this actually means EDT and NOT EST, and place the event correctly.

That might be asking a bit too much, but what's the closest I can get to this without writing a custom app?

Comment: I have never seen Google Calendar do that. As far as I can see, it's smart enough to know that the time you set is in DST or not. For one thing, my recurring events would be wrong for half of the year. As long as your timezone is set properly in your settings you shouldn't need to do anything. Lots of interesting information at this link: https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/2367918 (Basically, unless a country changes its DST rules since you created the event, there should be no problem.)

Comment: @AlE.: This is not what I get.  I updated the post with images, and you can see that I'm specifying the time, and even trying to help it by specifying EDT, but it still creates the event in EST.

Comment: Because you're trying to outsmart it. Just put the time in. You won't suddenly find yourself with an 11 o'clock appointment after the DST switch.